# Regarding multiple device-tree(dtb) on single image

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I am using openwrt to build an embedded system image - and wondering whether I can add multple device tree files (dtb) in single image.

Basically, I have multiple hardwares which needs to share the single image file for all.
Upgrade will happen with the single image for different hardware.

Question is, current our boot-loader code has some kind of code to "override" some important params based on hardware type.

Rather than doing aboves, i want to put multiple device tree files (dtb) and make boot loader to load / read - right dtb file and pass the params to kernel based on hardware type.

Is it possible? If so, what would be the way to do it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think so. If you have a boot loader that can do a selection, I think _U-Boot_ can, then no issues with that. Just pack several DTBs into blob.

Comment: U-Boot for Wandboard chooses a DTB in SPL. U-Boot for Raspberry also detects the hardware and provides the correct device tree.

Comment: The question is - on what basis the U-Boot makes the selection? Is it "try to boot 1st, if failed boot 2nd device tree"?